# python - producing an array with random numbers from 1 to 9 in each row and column

Tags: python, r

I currently have the following R code:

```
m <- matrix(NA, nrow = 9, ncol = 9)
for (i in 1:9){
  m[i,] <- sample(9)
}
```

I'm new to Python and am looking to reproduce this but with a random sample from 1 to 9 in each column with no repeats as well as in each row. can anyone show me along the right lines for this?

Comment: Is this in native Python or are you using libraries like `numpy` ?

Comment: using  `numpy` currently for this @JonClements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use python's numpy library.

```
from numpy.random import randint

low = 1
high = 10
nrow = 9
ncol = 9

m = randint(low,high,size = (nrow,ncol))

print(m)


[[9 9 1 3 4 1 7 9 1]
 [8 1 2 9 1 6 5 6 1]
 [2 5 8 7 6 8 4 6 8]
 [7 1 8 7 4 8 1 3 2]
 [9 1 8 7 6 3 4 7 4]
 [5 8 2 4 5 9 8 6 3]
 [9 9 7 6 5 5 9 8 2]
 [3 3 5 5 3 1 8 9 5]
 [2 9 5 6 5 9 6 7 9]]
```

This will create a numpy matrix with 9 rows and 9 columns which will contain random integers in the interval [low,high)

You can take a look at the function's manual at:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html

If you want to have unique values on each row then you can use this approach:

```
import numpy as np

m = np.zeros((9,9))
vals = np.arange(1,10)
for i in range(0,9):
    m[i,:] = np.random.choice(vals,size=9,replace=False)
print(m.astype(int))

[[8 9 4 3 6 1 7 5 2]
 [1 3 8 6 9 2 7 5 4]
 [4 1 9 6 8 2 7 5 3]
 [7 8 6 3 5 2 9 1 4]
 [3 8 7 9 5 4 2 1 6]
 [1 2 5 8 7 3 4 6 9]
 [8 5 4 9 1 3 6 7 2]
 [8 4 9 6 1 5 3 2 7]
 [3 2 4 5 6 1 8 9 7]]
```

To do the same on each column you can change the for loop to this:

```
for i in range(0,9):
    m[:,i] = np.random.choice(vals,size=9,replace=False)
```

Comment: is there a way to make it so that there are no repeats in each row or column?

Comment: @Hew.r Yes, there is. I have updated my answer to include your request